# Error in getting infowindow marker values from database in creation of map using jsp

Tags: database, jsp, dictionary, marker, infowindow

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>GMap</title>
<style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

</head>

<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDF4xc24ce0hMfmjiTdtDhDhuH0b9fvs5c&sensor=false">
</script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1100px;height:580px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng('17.241704110314977','74.98103292570762')
var mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:12,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);     
var marker;
var flightPlanCoordinates=new Array();

function initialize(point,imei,speed,altitude)
{   
        var x=point;
        {
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position:x,
            map: map
            });
           var cnt;
           var contentString;
           var j=2;
           var arrayinfo=new Array();
           for(cnt=1;cnt<point.length;cnt++)
           {
           contentString = '<div id="content">'+
           '<font color="purpal"><b>Sr no : </b></font>';" +j+ "+ '<br /> ' +
            '<font color="purpal"><b>imei: 352840065108626</b></font>';"+imei+"  +'<br /> ' +
             '<font color="purpal"><b>Speed : </b></font>';"+speed+" + '<br /> ' +
           '<font color="purpal"><b>Altitude : </b></font>';"+altitude+"+ '<br /> ' + '</div>';
           arrayinfo.push(arrayinfo);
           j++;
          return arrayinfo;
           }
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: arrayinfo,
             maxWidth: 400
            }); 
        }
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(arrayinfo, marker);
  });

flightPlanCoordinates.push(marker.getPosition());
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
}); 
}

<%
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tracking_hpcl";
try{

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tracking_hpcl", "root","root");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
    s.executeQuery ("select * from data_yday where imei='352840065108626' and gpsdatetime between '2016-09-30 07:00:00' and '2016-09-31 07:00:00' order by gpsdatetime asc;");
    ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ();


    out.print("var speed=new Array();");
    out.print("var altitude=new Array();");
    out.print("var imei=new Array();");
    int i = 0;
    int size=0;
    /* rs.last();
    size=rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst(); */
    out.print("var arr=new Array();");
    while(rs.next())
    {   
        String lat = rs.getString ("lat");
        String lng = rs.getString ("lng");
        String imei=rs.getString ("imei"); 
        System.out.println("\n imei="+imei);
         out.print("var imeiinarr='"+imei+"';");
            out.print("imei.push(imeiinarr);");

        /* Timestamp datetime=rs.getString("datetime");
        System.out.println("\n datetime="+datetime);
        out.print("var datimeind='"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(datetime)+"';");
        out.print("datetime.push(datimeind);");*/

         String speed=rs.getString("speed");
        System.out.println("\n speed="+speed); 
         out.print("var speedinarr='"+speed+"';");
          out.print("speed.push(speedinarr);");  

       /* String battery=rs.getString("battery");
        System.out.println("\n battery="+battery);
        out.print("var batteryind='"+battery+"';");
        out.print("battery.push(batteryinarr);"); */

      String altitude=rs.getString("altitude");
        System.out.println("\n altitude="+altitude); 
         out.print("var altitudeinarr='"+altitude+"';"); 
         out.print("altitude.push(altitudeinarr);");   

        out.print("var point = new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+","+lng+","+imei+","+speed+","+altitude+");\n");
        out.print("arr.push(point);\n"); 
       out.print("initialize(point,arr,imei,speed,altitude);");
            i++;    
    }

    rs.close ();
    s.close ();  
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%> 
</script>


</html>
```

I am working on a web application with Java EE and I would like to dynamically add markers to the Google map placed on my JSP page with coordinates from my database. I have the following code, but I can't pinpoint the issue

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Show us the output.